# extract only file name instead of path+filename

Tags: linux, shell, loops, for-loop

```
for i in ../fromXP/splite_files/F1*.fasta
do
  ./Repeatmasker $i > "${i%.fasta}"_output.txt
done
```

I have a folder splite_files which contains F1_1.fasta, F1_2.fasta,.... F1_20533.fasta. 
Right now, I am trying to check repeat of each fasta file and output result to F1_1_output.txt. 
But, the command above only gives me ../fromXP/Split_files/F1_1_output.txt instead of F1_1_output.txt 
Please gives me some advise. Thanks!

Comment: [basename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in "${FILES[@]}"; 
do 
  bname=$(basename "$f" .fasta); 
  echo "./RepeatMasker $f > ${bname}_output.txt" >> runfile.txt; 
done
```

This is what I got to resolve this issue. 
Thanks!